# No output is generated when using reference data in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have written a simple query and join it with a json reference data. I can see correct results when testing the query in "Test results" tab. However, no output is generated when starting the job.

I have confirmed that the output blob is created when no join with reference data is used in the query.

Any help is appreciated. The sample reference json follows:

```
[
   {
      "DeviceId":"DEV-021",
      "Brand":"brand01",
      "Model":"model01"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flat json structure instead of array. It should give you the output

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried that with no luck. The "test query" always returns the correct result so it is odd that I get no output. This is the json I used before: >>> `{
      "DeviceId":"DEV-021",
      "Brand":"brand01",
      "Model":"model01"
   }`

Comment: Does activity logs or diagnostic logs show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Check the path you specified in the reference data, maybe it is not correct or you did not specify the file name. Does it contain something like {date}/{time}/filename.json?

If you forget to specify the file name, it does not work as well. 
And if you are testing the job, usually you specify the file manually and that is why your query works.